# Randomly sum values, add/subtract them up, until you have a value match php

Tags: php

I have an array of values floats:

```
$values =array(); // array(6) { [0]=> string(8) "90.00000" [1]=> string(9) "481.93000" [2]=> string(8) "38.11000" [3]=> string(8) "-4.40000" [4]=> string(9) "120.00000" [5]=> string(10) "-120.00000" }

$value_to_be_found = 123.710;
```

Now e need something that sums them up random until found the $value_to_be_found.

in this case the answer would be:

90.00000

38.11000

-4.40000

Comment: You're expected to show us some indication that you've tried to solve your problem as it stands, this question is too broad and is also [likely to attract downvotes](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: The problem is that i realy don't know how to do it.

Comment: I don't know what "sums them up random" means

Comment: Then it seems you need a tutorial, and that's not what this site is about.

Comment: Chris Haas, trys to find out the correct sum of array entrys to find out the value ?

Comment: Doesn't sound like randomness has anything to do with it. Also, are you guaranteed that the solution is even achievable?

Comment: El_Vanja, good question, solution may probably be not found, in some cases. You're right its not realy ramdom, it's more sequential.

Comment: So you want to loop through an array of items (maybe by using a `foreach`), right? If the current item is what you are searching for you want to `break` out of the loop then, but otherwise you want to add that to a grand total and `continue` looping? Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Chris Hass, kind off a simple foreach would not work, cause in the example that i posted, there is a jump on the second value.

Comment: What is a "jump" in the context of an array?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I believe he means non-consecutive array elements.

Comment: @user1228825 Look, this isn't a trivial task. Finding out if any combination of these parameters can produce the searched number by summing them will require multiple loops. Because the solution could be anything from that exact value already being in the array up to having to add every single item in the array to produce it. Your code would have to test every combination between those two edge cases. Seems like a good exercise for the brain. Start with the simplest solution; check if that value is already in the array. Then write something to check if two numbers can produce it and so on.

Comment: (1) Doing calculations with strings is not ideal you should use a numeric value in you array. (2) You're going to have to research maths algorithms to determine the best way to check different values until you have the one you want. Some predetermined "big o" patterns might be a google starting point. (3) This seems weird, I mean odd scenarios exist, but be really sure you are approaching this in the right way. Are the array values always going to add up to a given specific number? Why is this needed this way, etc :)

Comment: Oh, I see, produce every combination of every item looking for a summation. I get it now.

Comment: This question actually does exactly what you want. [Find numbers that equals a sum in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687975/find-numbers-that-equals-a-sum-in-an-array). You are going to have to solve floating point issues. The best way is to multiple everything by something like 10000 (depending on how many decimals you have), performing integer-only math, and then divide when you are done.

Comment: @ChrisHaas good find :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of optimization that could be done for this, but I think the source data could be optimized more than the loops, so I'm going to leave it.

Assuming you have this as your input data, specifically an array of float-like values stored as strings, and a search value stored as a float.

```php
$numbers = ['90.00000', '481.93000', '38.11000', '-4.40000', '120.00000', '-120.00000'];
$sum = 123.710;
```

The below code should work, I've inside

```php
function _searchRecursive($numbers, $sum, &$result, $index = 0, $total = 0, $solution = '')
{
    // The logic in the block following this one works on strings, this converts it back to an integer array
    if ($total === $sum) {
        $result = array_map('intval', explode(' ', trim($solution)));
        return true;
    }

    // This logic is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687982/231316
    if ($index < count($numbers)) {
        return _searchRecursive($numbers, $sum, $result, $index + 1, $total, $solution) or _searchRecursive($numbers, $sum, $result, $index + 1, $total + $numbers[$index], $solution . ' ' . $numbers[$index]);
    }

    return false;
}

function search(array $numbersAsStrings, $sum)
{
    // This is a magic multiple, adjust for your data or else things won't work!
    $multiplier = 100000;

    // Clone the array so that we can return strings later
    $numbersAsInts = $numbersAsStrings;

    // Create an integer array by multiplying each number and casting to int
    foreach ($numbersAsInts as &$number) {
        $number = (int)($number * $multiplier);
    }

    // The previous loop is by reference so it is best to clean up
    unset($number);

    // Scale our search term, too
    $sum = (int)($sum * $multiplier);

    // The recursive search will place the value into this, if found
    $result = null;
    _searchRecursive($numbersAsInts, $sum, $result);

    // Nothing was found
    if (!is_array($result)) {
        return null;
    }

    // Search the original string array and re-match with our int array
    $finalRet = [];
    foreach ($result as $int) {
        foreach ($numbersAsStrings as $string) {
            if ($int === (int)($string * $multiplier)) {
                $finalRet[] = $string;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    return $finalRet;
}

$result = search($numbers, $sum);
```

Online version here: https://3v4l.org/Y9T8K

Comment: Chirs Hass, many tanks m8 it works like a charm :), only if you feed it more than 30 values it takes a bit :)